# Overloading input and output streams outside of the class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm trying to overload the input and output streams in a class. In the header file I declare the member functions:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &, const MyClass &);
    friend istream &operator >>(istream &, MyClass &);
};
```

Then in a .cpp file, I'm trying to define the functions. The way I write them looks like this:

```
ostream& MyClass::operator<<(ostream &strm, const MyClass &obj)
{
    //...
}

istream& MyClass:operator>>(istream &strm, MyClass &obj)
{
    //...
}
```

The problem is that in the .cpp file where I define the member functions, Visual Studio is telling me that the function header is not correct. I'm sure that Visual Studio is right, but I don't know how to fix it, or why it is wrong. All the solutions I've found online have just written the operator<< and operator>> as inline member functions, but I want to know why I can't write the definitions outside of the class.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that because it indeed isn't correct. Those are free functions, not member. `MyClass:` doesn't belong in front of them (and even if they were members, that's still wrong, it would be two colons; not one).

Comment: Terminology: input and output streams are **objects** (or references to objects); you cannot overload them. What you're asking about is overloading **inserters** and **extractors**; those are overloaded operators, which are a particular form of function. Functions can be overloaded.

Answer (score -1):

You might find the following site helpful. You can play around with the code if you want by clicking on Live Demo. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm